# Error while installing QGIS with conda

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, pyqgis-3, conda

I'm trying to install QGIS through conda `$conda install -c conda-forge qgis` but got the following error

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py36h17a0993_4
  - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3 -> numexpr==2.6.5=py36h7bf3b9c_0
  - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3 -> scikit-learn==0.19.1=py36h7aa7ec6_0
  - qgis
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I've tried update one of those by `$conda install -c conda-forge numexpr` however I am still getting the same error afterwards. Any hints?

Comment: Just tried  a minimal `conda create -c conda-forge -n qgisenv python=3.4 qgis spyder pyodbc matplotlib scipy numpy` but I"ve got a nasty `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - matplotlib
  - qgis
`
Can't they work together for real?

Comment: Only QGIS 2.18 is available for Linux via conda-forge and it requires Python 2.7. You can't use Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Only QGIS 2.18 is available for Linux via conda-forge and it requires Python 2.7.

Try:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n qgisenv qgis
```

You won't be able to install `matplotlib` though. I'm not sure where the fault is.

If you restrict packages to the conda-forge channel (`conda create/install -c conda-forge --override-channels etc...`) then QGIS 2 conflicts with conda-forge matplotlib.

If you allow packages from the default channels (`conda create/install -c conda-forge etc...`) then matplotlib from defaults requires Qt 5.9 but QGIS requires Qt 5.6. I can't find a way around it at the moment

Comment: Hi @Luke, I've tried that too... 
`$ conda create -c conda-forge -n qgisenv python=2.7 qgis spyder pyodbc matplotlib scipy numpy 
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - matplotlib
  - qgis
`
Since I'm still learning both python and qgis, I think I'll go without mathplotlib... that I was including as a way to plot some data that I'll be querying from an sqlserver (already being fed by a sensors network).

Comment: `conda create -c conda-forge -n qgisenv01 python=2.7 qgis spyder pyodbc scipy numpy` didn't work either... now spyder cant be launched... `anaconda3/envs/qgisenv01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py:211: RuntimeWarning: Selected binding "pyqt5" could not be found, using "pyqt"`

Comment: I think you'll have to raise an issue with conda-forge.  Not sure where the fault is.  If you restrict packages to the conda-forge channel (`conda create/install -c conda-forge --override-channels etc...`) then QGIS 2 conflicts with conda-forge matplotlib.  If you allow packages from the default channels (`conda create/install -c conda-forge etc...`) then matplotlib from defaults requires Qt 5.9 but QGIS requires Qt 5.6.  I can't find a way around it at the moment.